# Is there an R package that runs frequentist zero-one inflated beta models?

Tags: r, frequentist, beta-regression, one-inflation

I have a set of proportion data (below) with a many 1s.  I would like to run a one inflated beta model in R, and want to use frequentest statistics. However the only zero-one inflated beta package I can find is `zoib` which is Bayesian. It seems that a frequentest approach is possible (Elysia, 2014). Does an R package exist that allows this approach?

```
dput(ex.dat.new)
structure(list(predictor = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("Asoca", "bida", "coma", 
"cyro", "melo", "oeno", "pano", "sena", "sida", "soam", "soda", 
"verb"), class = "factor"), response = c(1, 1, 0.981270985, 1, 
0.911258698, 1, 0.249252611, 0.671639842, 0.575247687, 0.943358751, 
0.470602887, 0.875696109, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.131273134, 0.479774791, 
0.497419936, 0.54108693, 0.838144234, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.868294819, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.305218209, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.095933078, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.217037264, 0.410118055, 0.173707357, 0.200733967, 
0.469833694, 0.208464348, 0.407013896, 0.846212651, 0.299872736, 
0.965380984, 0.251676335, 0.806683955, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.934555905, 
0.564142452, 1, NA, 1, 0.029682211), total = c(109.98, 46.834, 
293.662, 197.144, 59.927, 7.33, 70.579, 222.125, 201.767, 43.802, 
417.541, 143.117, 70.658, 167.073, 666.542, 49.872, 258.847, 
93.83, 56.036, 116.17, 378.5276, 12.209, 163.58, 182.329, 209.913, 
411.1590278, 1003.223, 29.3499744, 95.896, 160.8383437, 124.437, 
52.017, 187.045, 132.032, 67.188, 86.12, 171.189, 21.27, 29.69, 
106.1, 77.14, 56.185, 68.97225736, 17.475, 539.401, 5.9, 49.256, 
12.854, 342.015, 250.562, 2177.605021, 748.1001011, 1035.573167, 
275.414, 660.717, 323.102, 1273.727, 285.97, 212.368, 140.366, 
420.044, 54.295, 802.118, 150.612, 157.469, 85.275, 368.131, 
35.998, 349.624, 0, 13.207, 191.731)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-72L))
```

Garcia, Elysia. "Frequentist, Bayesian, and Zero-One Inflated Beta Regression Models." PhD diss., 2014.
https://baylor-ir.tdl.org/handle/2104/8975

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there an R package that runs frequentist zero-one inflated beta models?"
Yes. `gamlss`.